# Why don't I see these two files in my React project, "webpack.config.dev" and "webpack.config.prod"?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have executed this command `npm run eject` and I got several new files appeared in my React project but I don't see these two files, ***"webpack.config.dev.js"*** and ***"webpack.config.prod.js"*** .

What is wrong in my project?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is wrong with your project, Its just the way `create-react-app` works

You wont see `webpack.config.dev.js` and `webpack.config.prod.js` because those are not embedded in `react-scripts`, instead you will find the webpack configuration in `config/webpack.config.js`

When you run `npm run eject`

that script will move all the webpack & webpackDevServer configuration from `react-scripts` to the App Root giving you all the webpack configuration and related files and scripts

Comment: I am watching tutorials and the instructor is changing **style-loader**. His idea to make class names specific to components, not the whole application. So I don't know how do I follow him since I don't see those two files. He used **localIdentName** property during those changes.

Comment: what is he doing to `style-loader` is he adding a new style loader??? can you just update the question with what you intend to do exactly

Comment: What I understood from the tutorial is that class names are going to be replaced automatically by random names and the reason to do that is to reuse same class names in our components. The instructor said we are enabling CSS module. He used this line to generate those random class names `localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'`. I did not update my question because it is not about this topic.

Comment: @Tanaka I have faced the same issue on react 16.13.1 version. I think if we just rename the css file with .module.css extension then you can achieve this.Because with .module.css extension react supports css modules by default.